# the number of same record until this row

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, count, sequence

Is it possible to retrieve current number of same record for each row by using oracle pl/sql?

For example,
I have class table which consists of  id, name, age columns

I want to have the sequence of student with the same name and age entering the class, assuming that id is countering up without altering data structure.

Thanks.

Regards,

Jim

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I entirely get what you're asking for; you have an odd turn of phrase.  An example of input data and expected result is always useful.

Perhaps something like this:

```
select id, name, age
from   your_table
where (name, age) in 
   ( select name. age
     from your_table
     group by name, age
     having count(id) > 1 )
order by name, age, id
/
```

You could solve this with analytics.  However, you still need an outer query to filter out the records which aren't duplicated, so I'm not sure what you'd gain:

```
select * from (
    select id, name, age
            , count(id) over (partition by name, age) as dup_count
    from   your_table )
where dup_count > 1
order by name, age, id
/
```

Comment: Yes I am looking for the analytic one, but I am not sure why I have to filter dup_count to be more than 1. Anyhow, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure either, but it sounds to me something related to analytic functions. Take this as an example, look at srlno column, calculated using analytic functions:

```
SELECT empno, deptno, hiredate,
ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER (PARTITION BY
deptno ORDER BY hiredate
NULLS LAST) SRLNO
FROM emp
WHERE deptno IN (10, 20)
ORDER BY deptno, SRLNO;

EMPNO  DEPTNO HIREDATE       SRLNO
------ ------- --------- ----------
  7782      10 09-JUN-81          1
  7839      10 17-NOV-81          2
  7934      10 23-JAN-82          3
  7369      20 17-DEC-80          1
  7566      20 02-APR-81          2
  7902      20 03-DEC-81          3
  7788      20 09-DEC-82          4
  7876      20 12-JAN-83          5
```

More on analyltic functions:
http://www.orafaq.com/node/55

Remember, is  a better approach if you can achieve your goal with a SQL instead of PL/SQL.

Comment: This would have been a better answer if you had tailored the sample code to an example which actually addressed the OP's requirement.

Comment: @APC, ok, you're rigth. Next time I'll try to fit more my answer! :)